# New Google Permissions policy: READ_SMS and similar

Tags: android, android-permissions

I developed an app that asks the user for READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and SEND_SMS permissions. Now Google updated the Permissions policy, so my app will be removed automatically from Play Store, if I don't remove those permissions in the manifest.

I already compiled the form to request an exception, but I'm not sure Google will grant the exception in my app.

I couldn't understand if this problem affects only Play Store. what happens if I distribute my app directly by sending apk? Will the user be able to install the app with those permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Google requires that must actively register the app as the device's default SMS or Auxiliary Handler by Users selves when using READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, ROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS, etc.

If you see similar warnings in the Google Play console and don't process them, chances are that they will be removed from Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they will not grant exception. I made six attempts already and all of them have been refused. So I give up here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
 you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, 
 provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)